# Handling lfs.dir when access to directory is denied

Tags: lua, filesystems

The lfs module allows reading a directory using the `lfs.dir` iterator. If the directory cannot be accessed (e.g. because permissions do not allow it), an error is raised.

I could check that directory can be read like this:

```
local status, err = pcall(lfs.dir, "mydir")

if not status then
  print("error occured", err)
else
  for file in lfs.dir("mydir") do
    print("file:", file)
  end
end
```

However, this means calling `lfs.dir` twice. Not sure how much overhead that is, but given that I am working on a tool that scans huge directory structures very quickly, I would very much like to avoid it. Another solution would be to wrap the loop in a function and `pcall` that function. However, I was wondering whether the pcall can be built in the iterator itself, like creating a custom iterator as a "safe" wrapper around `lfs.dir()` that would allow me to silently ignore directories that cannot be read. How can I do that? And how much overhead would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can invoke `lfs.dir` only once:

```
local status, err_or_iter, ud, v3, v4 = pcall(lfs.dir, "mydir")

if not status then
  print("error occured", err_or_iter)
else
  for file in err_or_iter, ud, v3, v4 do
    print("file:", file)
  end
end
```

Comment: huh, what is v3 and v4? [lfs documentation](https://lunarmodules.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html) mentions only two arguments...

Comment: `lfs.dir` [implementation](https://github.com/lunarmodules/luafilesystem/blob/master/src/lfs.c#L715-L718) returns 4 arguments on Lua 5.4

Comment: Any idea what they are? `v3` seems to be `nil`, but what is `v4`? And what would they be used in the loop for?

Answer (score 2):

## Using `pcall`

You don't have to look at thee implementation details of LFS to use `pcall`: The [Lua reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5) tells you that there will be exactly 4 values evaluated to iterate a generic for:

> The loop starts by evaluating explist to produce four values: an iterator function, a state, an initial value for the control variable, and a closing value.

Thus you can use `pcall` *for any generic for iterator* as follows:

```lua
local status, iterator_or_err, state, control_var, closing_val = pcall(lfs.dir, "mydir")
if status then
    for file in iterator_or_err, state, control_var, closing_val do
        print("file:", file)
    end
else
    print("error occurred", iterator_or_err)
end
```

Perhaps slightly more elegant would be capturing the return values in a table:

```
local t = {pcall(lfs.dir, "mydir")}
if t[1] then
    for file in table.unpack(t, 2) do
        print("file:", file)
    end
else
    print("error occurred", t[2])
end
```

Downside: This creates a garbage table. The most elegant solution is to use `xpcall`:

## Using `xpcall`

Whenever you have to handle vararg returns, `xpcall` is handy because Lua will call a handler you provide with the status & the vararg.

```lua
xpcall(lfs.dir, function(status, ...)
    if status then
        for file in ... do
            print("file:", file)
        end
    else
        print("error occurred", ...)
    end
end, "mydir")
```